# Best time complexity of sorting numbers in range [1...n log n]

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, sorting, radix-sort

given an array $A$ of $n$ numbers in range $1$ to $n\log n$, what is the time complexity of the best method to sort them?

The answer is $O(n)$ but I don't understand this. of course counting sort itself is irrelevant, perhaps radix sort with base changing is the way to go, but I'm not sure of to change the base of $n\log n$.

Comment: each number has O(log n + log log n) = O(log n) bits, so radix sort requires O(log n) passes. I think the answer is incorrect since authors forgot about this part of equation. Overall, radix sort is O(n) only for fixed-size numbers.

Comment: OTOH, if you process O(log n) bits on each pass, you will need to use fixed number of passes. This means using O(n) extra memory, so why not? Anyway it's pure theory which is far from real setting

Comment: On the contrary, the word RAM model is supposed to be *more* realistic than the bit complexity model.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus how it works with numbers in given range? Is it suppose that each cell can hold arbitrary number? Or that each cell can hold fixed number of bits? By unrealistic I mean that radix sort on real computers became much slower when you use more than ~~256 bins in radix sort. So on real computers you will use 256 bins or so, in theoretical setting you may use O(log n) bits

Comment: @YuvalFilmus already found "By definition: A register is a location with both an address (a unique, distinguishable designation/locator equivalent to a natural number) and a content – a single natural number" --- of course, ability to hold ARBITRARY natural number is completely unrealistic

Comment: @Bulat In the word RAM model, each memory location contains a machine word, which is $O(\log n)$ bits long (where $n$ is the input length).

Comment: @YuvalFilmus thank you, this makes sense. And now my point - in ppractice, you should use ~~256 bins to fit CPU cache structure (TLB, write combining buffers...). So you need to make O(log n) radix sort passes. In theory, you can use counting sort or fixed number of passes

Answer (score 2):

Note in the [RAM model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_machine), indirection always takes constant time regardless of how large the address is, so each process of radix sort with base $b$ takes $O(n+b)$ time. As a result, the radix sort takes $O((n+b)\log_b(n\log n))=O((n+b)\log_b n)$ time. Choosing $b=n$ makes the asymptotic time linear.

Edit: as suggested by [Thinh D. Nguyen](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/97579/best-time-complexity-of-sorting-numbers-in-range-1-n-log-n/97612?noredirect=1#comment207705_97592), since extracting each digit under base $b$ requires division and modular arithmetic, which are not supported by the standard RAM model, we may want to use the [word RAM model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_RAM) instead.

Comment: b=n means counting sort. But you don't need to go that far, any b^const=n will suffice

Comment: oh, I was wrong. b=n means two passes, each with n bins, since n log n < n^2. Now the book answer finally makes sense for me!

Comment: Though RAM model is historically important to the theory of computation from 20th century. It is [Word RAM model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_RAM) that is widely used in the algorithm community. Yijie Han's nearly-linear deterministic sorting algorithm is given in this model.

Comment: Well, Yuval has already pointed this out several hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

*Theoretically*, there is no **linear sorting** algorithm if you consider only <strike>*nice*</strike> standard RAM model like (RAM model that was used to define recursive function and more recent model like Word RAM model).

Radix sort cannot help. Since pushing up the base to $b=n$ like in the [answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/97592/90560) of xskxzr, you need to extract the $b$-base digits.

In any theoretical RAM model, bitwise arithmetics are constant-time. Taking modulo an $O(\log(n))$-long number like $b=n$ is cumbersome.

*One last note*: if you still think that this can be done in linear time. That is OK, but it will never be a mathematical theorem. For otherwise, sorting with number in $[1, n^{O(1)}]$ can be done in linear time with radix sort from the very beginning of **every algorithm course** even in the $O(\log(n))$ word RAM model. But, **that is just wrong**. One cannot ignore the $polylog(n)$ overhead to simulate modular arithmetics. For students without sharp theoretical minds, that is acceptable.

*For an algorithm course, one can assume **unit-cost RAM**. That helps students to understand the big picture and neglect the details in time bounds analysis.*

Comment: Linear is only in the case of ranges like $[1, \mathrm{constant}]$

Comment: Same misconception from books: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/48836/how-do-i-sort-these-elements-in-on-time

Comment: What do you mean by "nice"? "Taking modulo an $O(\log(n))$-long number like $b=n$ is cumbersome" I think this is from a practical view, not a theoretical view. Theoretically, a RAM or word RAM is able to take modulo an $O(\log(n))$-long number in constant time.

Comment: Never mind the speed of CPU instructions here. Both RAM model and Word RAM model have no MOD instruction. You have to simulate it in $polylog(n)$ time.

Comment: You are right. I didn't realize that RAM does not support division.

Comment: Who said the RAM model doesn't support division?

Comment: Set of instructions: INC, DEC, JMP, indirect access, bit shift, etc. No primitive instruction for division. It is only practical CPUs such as Intel, AMD that have this instruction.

Comment: What counts as "nice"?  What do you mean by "that is just wrong" and what is the justification for that statement?  Regarding "it will never be a mathematical theorem", surely it depends on the model of computation, and there are models of computation where sorting can be done in linear time.  Can you state these claims in a more precise way, where the assumptions are made explicit?

Comment: Linear sorting with $\Omega(log(n))$-long element can only be done with **unit-cost RAM**. For more useful model like logarithmic-cost RAM, linear sorting is still out of reach. Of course, a formal lowerbound of $\omega(n)$ is also not proven.

Comment: Even in *unit-cost RAM* model, there is still no known linear sorting algo.